# remove event listener as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, event-listener

I'm almost finished with a quiz of mine. I've encountered an error which I have finally pinpointed. But first I'll tell you some background info on the code.

**Background**

On stage, there exist 4 button components registered as movie clips. These are later stored in an array. When a certain icon is clicked on stage, these buttons are to be activated by adding event listeners to all of them. When a button is pressed, it checks if it's the 'correct' answer and removes the event listeners.

Now I have done extensive checks and narrowed down the problem to the following.

### **Code**

*This function will add button listeners to each button recursively. Note that the variable 'num' is a fixed integer between 1 - 4 which is generated earlier into the code and used for many 'if' cases.*

```
function addButtonListener(num:int):void
{
    for (var obj:Object in _buttons)
    {   
        _buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkans(num));
    }
}
```

---

*This function is basically the opposite and also disables the buttons*

```
function removeButtonListener(num:int):void
{
    for (var obj:Object in _buttons)
    {
        _buttons[obj].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkans(num));
        _buttons[obj].enabled = false;
    }
}
```

---

Now one thing I noticed through the use of **trace** functions is that the code correctly adds the button listeners but it does not remove them.

*This function calls for each button to be removed.*

```
function checkans(num:int):Function
{
    return function(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (e.currentTarget.label == xmlNodes)
        {
            points = points + (2 * num);
            scoreBox.text = points.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("Incorrect!");        
        }
            if(myText.parent){
            myText.parent.removeChild(myText)
        }
            closeShowQuestion(num);//closes a previous function
            removeButtonListener(num);//Should I pass this variable into the end function?
            GoFishing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fish);//Starts the process again.
        }
    }
```

So am I removing the event listeners incorrectly?

Do you need to see more code to be sure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use function in a function? Any reason?

Comment: I used it to pass a variable continuously to all the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeEventListener` must use the SAME function that was used in `addEventListener`.

Your `checkans` function always returns a NEW function, so it will not be the same for add and remove.

If you have to pass a `num` into your listener function, do it other way. Make it a property of a button or store externally etc.

Comment: Ok I'm going to make the variables public and store them from the start.

Comment: Amazing! So I edited a couple functions to use a variable which basically took the purpose of num. A couple reference cleanups later, and I had perfectly working code! 

Thank you very much!